# make an image go to the same speed of the finger in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touch

so I have a scrollView and an image inside? My problem is that when I scroll down the scroll view my image doesn't go to the same speed of my finger. What I would like is that this image goes to the same speed of my finger, thus my finger center is the image center . How can I do this please, sorry for my english I'm french /

Comment: Please post some of your code, you must be doing something strange.

Comment: I just add a scroll view in interface builder then in my view did load myscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(37,449 ); that's all

Comment: Then what does "doesn't go to the same speed of my finger" mean? What does it do?

Comment: What I want is that image.center is my finger.center that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to setup a delegate for the `UIScrollView` and update the image position in this method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView;
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    // Now use offset to update the image's position.
    // Be fast this method is called OFTEN!
}
```

Comment: I tried many time but I can't update the image's position, because I don't know how

Comment: @bernard: `theImage.frame = newFrame;`?